# Monaca/Onsen UI でDBの内容でons-list-itemを生成しても、一番最後の物しか表示されない

Tags: javascript, monaca, onsen-ui, html5

MonacaでonsenUIのons-list内のons-list-itemをDBから取得したデータで複数生成しようと考えています。
下のように記述しているのですが、ons-list-itemがJavascriptのfor文の最後の周回で取得した物しか生成されません。
初心者でわからないことだらけなので、助言していただければ大変ありがたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

index.html

> ```
> <ons-list id="ons-list">
>      <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item" id="ons-list-item">
>            <!--ここにDBから取得して表示-->
>      </ons-list-item> 
> </ons-list>
> ```

DB.js

> ```
> function DBLoad(){
>     //DB接続
>     var db = openDatabase('DBName', '1.0', 'DataBase', 1024 * 1024 * 5);
>     db.readTransaction(function(transaction){
>         transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DBtable',[],
>             function(transaction, result){
>                 var onsList = document.getElementById('ons-list');
>                 //DBの結果の数だけons-list-item生成
>                 for (var i = 0; i< result.rows.length; i++){
>                     var ResultSet = result.rows.item(i).task;
>                     var onsListItem = document.getElementById('ons-list-item');
>                     onsListItem.innerHTML = "<ons-row>"+
>                                                 "<ons-col class = 'ons-col' width='20px' align='center'>"+
>                                                     "<ons-icon class='item-icon' icon='fa fa-building-o' size='20px'></ons-icon>"+
>                                                 "</ons-col>"+
>                                                 "<ons-col>"+
>                                                     "<header>"+
>                                                         "<span class='item-title' id='item-title'>"+ ResultSet +"</span><br>"
>                                                     "</header>"+
>                                                 "</ons-col>"+
>                                             "</ons-row>"
>                     ons.compile(onsListItem);
>                     onsList.appendChild(onsListItem);
>                 }
>             }
>         );
>     }); 
> }
> ```

回答があり解決しました！
for文の中でons-list-itemをcreateElementで生成してからinnerHTMLをする必要があったようです。
ありがとうございました。

> ```
>   var onsListItem = document.createElement("ons-list-item");
>                 onsListItem.innerHTML ="<ons-row>"+
>                                             "<ons-col class = 'ons-col' width='30px' align='center'>"+
>                                                 "<ons-icon class='item-icon' icon='fa fa-building-o' size='20px' fixed-width='false' style='color: blue'></ons-icon>"+
>                                             "</ons-col>"+
>                                             "<ons-col>"+
>                                                 "<header>"+
>                                                     "<span class='item-title' id='item-title'>"+ ResultSet +"</span><br>"+
>                                                     "<span class='item-label' id='item-label'>2015-3-12 9:00</span>"+
>                                                 "</header>"+
>                                             "</ons-col>"+
>                                         "</ons-row>";
>                 onsList.appendChild(onsListItem);
>                 ons.compile(onsListItem);
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onsListItem.innerHTMLの中身を毎回上書きしているので、最後のものしか生成されません。
for文でons-rowを生成するのではなくons-list-itemを生成してonsListに追加してみましょう。